# @vue-composition / How can I use asynchronous methods in setup()

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, web, vue-composition-api

```
<script lang="ts">
import { createComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";

import { SplashPage } from "../../lib/vue-viewmodels";

export default createComponent({
  async setup(props, context) {
    await SplashPage.init(2000, context.root.$router, "plan", "login");
  }
});
</script>
```

ERROR: "setup" must return a "Object" or a "Function", got "Promise"

Answer (score 20):

The `setup` function <s>must be synchronous</s> [can be `async` using **Suspense**](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/suspense-new-feature-in-vue-3/).

### How to avoid using async setup (obsolete answer)

An `onMounted` hook can be used with an `async` callback:

```
import { onMounted } from "@vue/composition-api";

// …
export default createComponent({
  setup(props, context) {
    onMounted(async () => {
      await SplashPage.init(2000, context.root.$router, "plan", "login");
    )};
  }
});
```

Or, it is always possible to call an asynchronous function without to await it:

```
SplashPage.init(2000, context.root.$router, "plan", "login")
  .catch(console.log);
```

In both cases, you'll have to take into account that the component will be rendered before the execution of the asynchronous function. A simple way to not display something that would depends on it is to use `v-if` in your template.

Comment: Must be synchronous you say, what about [this async setup](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/master/playground/views/ComponentWithData.vue#L15)?

Comment: @Greendrake You're right. I see that there is a way now, with `Suspense`. I will give a try to this new feature then I will come back here to update my answer.  https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/suspense-new-feature-in-vue-3/

Comment: that feature unfortunately will only work with vue3 not the vue2 composition-api

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution that works in my use-case. Maybe it will help. It is a bit like the lifestyle hook approach, but without needing it. It also doesn't need the `<Suspense>` tag which was "overkill" in my use-case.

The idea is to return a default value (the empty array in this case, but could be a "Loading..." splash page). Then, after the `async` has resolved, update the reactive prop (`menuItems` array here, but it could be the actual splash page contents or html or whatever).

I know this might not suit all use-cases but it is another approach that works.

Simplified code:

```js
setup () {
  const menuItems = ref([])

  const buildMenuItems = async () => {
     // eg get items from server, return an array of formatted items...
  }
  
  /* setTimeout(async () => {
    menuItems.value = await buildMenuItems()
  }, 0) */ 

  // or..
  ;(async () => {
    menuItems.value = await buildMenuItems()
  })()  

  return {
    menuItems
  } 
}
```

I tested it by making buildMenuItems() take 2 seconds and it all works fine.

**EDIT**: And then I discovered other ways (even for non TypeScript): [How can I use async/await in the Vue 3.0 setup() function using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117116/how-can-i-use-async-await-in-the-vue-3-0-setup-function-using-typescript)

Cheers,
Murray