# Vue.js - Composition API - Toggle Button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a Vue.js app. I am determined to understand the Composition API. However, the syntax throws me off a bit. I feel like I'm creating closures inside of closures, which leads me to believe I'm doing it wrong. I'm trying to set whether a button is enabled/disabled when my component loads. To demonstrate, I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kobtLy56/), which includes the following:

**example**

```
myApp.component("banner", 
  { 
    template: '<button :disabled="isDisabled">generate</button>',
    setup(props) {
      let isDisabled = true;
      function initializeButton() {
        fetch('<some-url>')
          .then(res => { isDisabled = !res.ok; } )
        ;
      }
      initializeButton();
      
      return {
        isDisabled
      };
    }
  }
);
```

However, this does not work. I've narrowed it down to the fact that `isDisabled` is not "accessible" in the `then` part of the promise. However, I'm unsure how to actually set `isDisabled` in `then`. Plus, I would *love* to put the `initializeButton` outside of the `setup` method, even that, I couldn't do though. I appreciate anyone's help who can help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: use an arrow function to capture the current context. `const initializeButton = () => { ... }`

Comment: @PierreSaid Thanks for your response. However, that didn't work. With an arrow function, `this` is `undefined`. If I do `console.log(this);` inside of the callback, I see `undefined`. `console.log(isDisabled);` prints `true` as desired. However, even if I manually enter `isDisabled = false;` *in* the callback, the button state doesn't change. Notably, if I manually set `isDisabled` to `false` outside of the `fetch` call, the button becomes enabled as desired. For that reason, I know a) the data-binding in my template is correct. b) I'm not setting it properly within `fetch`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an asynchronous setup method you need to use [`suspense`](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/suspense-new-feature-in-vue-3/).

[@vue-composition / How can I use asynchronous methods in setup()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230249/vue-composition-how-can-i-use-asynchronous-methods-in-setup/60260315#60260315)

Example :

```js
Vue.productionTip = false;

const Todo = {
  async setup(props) {
    const todo = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(r => r.json());
    return {
      todo
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Todo : {{ todo.title }}
    </div>
  `
};

const vm = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    Todo
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <Todo />
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</div>
```

Also `isDisabled` is not reactive. You need to use [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref) to make this varible reactive.

basic example for reactivity with ref:

```js
Vue.productionTip = false;

const vm = Vue.createApp({
  setup(props) {
    const count = Vue.ref(0);
    const inc = () => {
      count.value += 1;
    }
    return {
      count,
      inc
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  Count : {{ count }}
  <button @click="inc">+1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Since `initializeButton` is an asynchronous operation you should use the `await` syntax (https://javascript.info/async-await)

```js
async setup() {
  function async initializeButton() {
    return fetch('<some-url>').then(res => { isDisabled = !res.ok; } );
  }
  await initializeButton();
}
```