# How can I use async/await in the Vue 3.0 setup() function using Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

(This question has been answered for JavaScript, see below, but this question is specific for TypeScript, which behaves differently)

I'm trying to use async functionality in Vue3.0 using typescript.

Without **async** this code works nice:

```
// file: components/HelloWorld.vue

<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  async setup() { // <-- this works without 'async'
    const test = 'test'

    // await doSomethingAsynchronous()

    return {
      test,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

With `async setup()` the component "HelloWorld" disappears from the page, and the Firefox console tells me

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: node is null (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js)"
```

When I change `async setup()` to `setup()`, the code works,
but then I would not be able to use async/await inside the setup function.

So my question:
how do I use async/await inside the setup() function using Typescript?

**EDIT:**

The answer to this question: [why i got blank when use async setup() in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009348/why-i-got-blank-when-use-async-setup-in-vue3) shows that `async setup()` does work with JavaScript, so I would expect it to work in TypeScript as well.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try to use `onMounted` hook to manipulate asynchronous call :

```
 setup() {
    const users = ref([]);
    onMounted(async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      users.value = res.data;
      console.log(res);
    });

    return {
      users,
    };
  },
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-architecture-d0kiy?file=/src/App.vue)**

According to [official docs](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage) the **Best approach** is to use `async setup` in child component and wrap that component by `Suspense` component in the parent one :

**UserList.vue**

```html
<script  lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
    async setup() {
        //get users from jsonplacerholder using await fetch api 
        const users = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(res => res.json());

        return {
            users
        }
    }
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- list users -->
        <ul>
            <li v-for="user in users">{{ user.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Parent component**:

```html
<script lang="ts">

import UserList from "../components/tmp/UserList.vue";
...
</script>

   <div>
            <!-- Suspense component  to show users  -->
            <Suspense>
                <template #fallback>
                    <div>loading</div>
                </template>

                <UserList />
            </Suspense>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why is that the 'best approach'?

Comment: @LeeGoddard I guess that's because it is the recommended approach from Vue documentation. https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage

Comment: Such information might be best placed within the answer.

Comment: Great answer. However, as of January 2023, the doc says Suspense is an experimental feature, which means it probably isn't the best.

Comment: Agree with @joshua <Suspense> is an experimental feature and its API will likely change.

Comment: @SimonKlimek it can change internally but it will keep consumed in the same way, I see Evan You said it will be stable very soon

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Can you help point us to where he said that? I couldn't find anything with a quick Google. Meanwhile the official Vue docs at https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html still warn: "It is not guaranteed to reach stable status and the API may change before it does." I personally wouldn't use it until that's updated.

Comment: https://youtu.be/I5mGNB-4f0o?t=1094

Answer (score 26):

Another way of doing this:

```
 const users = ref([]);
 
 (async () => {
   const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
   users.value = res.data;
   console.log(res);
 })()

 return {
   users,
 }
```

And you don't have to wait for it to mount, this is similar to using created() with the options API.

Note: Don't forget to always have a semicolon ";" before the function statement, otherwise, JavaScript would think that the previous statement was supposed to return a function, the following code, for example, would cause a bug "ref([]) is not a function":

```
const users = ref([]) // No semicolon here

(async () => {
```

Another way of preventing this bug is to always have the semicolon on the same line of the function definition, the following code also works:

```
;(async () => {
```

Comment: Much cleaner! And beware not to put the executing brackets inside the grouping  brackets: you will get a TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: When you create a immediately invoked function you split the  thread into two running in parallel. This answer will always return an empty users and THEN update it. You should be using suspense and async setup instead. Unless you want this buggy experience of updating the UI.

Comment: Keep in mind that suspense is still considered an "Experimental feature" though. https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html

Answer (score 9):

To call API [even before](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram) the `beforeCreate()` lifecycle hook, there're a couple of ways:

1. Use a helper function (more elegant than `;(async () => {})()`):

```
// utils.ts
export const run = (asyncFn: () => Promise<void>) => asyncFn()
```

```js
// component.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { run } from './utils.ts'
  import { getUsers } from './api.ts'

  const users = ref([])

  run(async () => {
    // getUsers() gets called before beforeCreate()
    users.value = await getUsers()
    // ...
  })
</script>
```

2. Use promise chaining:

```js
// component.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { getUsers } from './api.ts'

  const users = ref([])

  // getUsers() gets called before beforeCreate()
  getUsers().then(users => {
    users.value = users
    // ...
  })
</script>
```

Comment: same problem as with @gustavodacrvi answer. In fact, even though the code runs before the `beforeCreate`, the data is resolved later than `onMounted` because any api call needs time and setup will not wait. It seems the closest "standard" thing to call api before mounting is to call it in async `onBeforeMount`

Comment: I can say further, even though commands inside async `onBeforeMount` will start in the proper moment, they again will be finished after the entire setup will be completed and the page will be mounted. And it's visible as "flashing". So it seems there is no way to do anything inside synchronous setup what should be done before the page will be mounted.  Either to use their "experimental" suspense or to execute the code in the `beforeEnter` router guard. The latter one will not fire if the params are just changed (e.g. user Id) so I basically don't know what to do.

Comment: @Niksr In most use cases, there's no point for the request to must finish before `mounted`.

Comment: You're right. No point to stop rendering to await API. Proper way to show e.g. placeholder or spinner and then replace it with actual data as soon as it was received.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. It's very similar to [gustavodacrvi' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525124/11208064), but if you don't like self-invoking functions as much as I do, you may find this version a bit nicer:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const users = ref<User[]>([])
const isLoading = ref(true)

async function fetchUsers() {
  users.value = await getUsers()
  isLoading.value = false
}

fetchUsers()
</script>
```

This requires you to take loading state into account, because `users` array will initially be empty and then updated.