# Vue <script setup> Top level await causing template not to render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I'm using the new  syntax in Vue 3 and I really like the idea of it, but once I tried to use a top level await I started to run in some problems.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory">
    <a class="btn btn-primary">Test button</a>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>Name</tr>
          <tr>Description</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, key) in inventory" :key="key">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { apiGetInventory, GetInventoryResponse } from '@/module/inventory/common/api/getInventory'

const inventory: GetInventoryResponse = await apiGetInventory()
</script>
```

As you can see it's not that complicated, the apiGetInventory is just an axios call so I won't bother going into that.
The problem is, that if I have this top level await, my template doesn't render anymore, it's just a blank page in my browser. If I remove the two lines of code, it works fine.
Also the promise seems to revolve just fine, if I place a
console.log(inventory) underneath it I get an array with objects all fine and dandy.

Anyone have a clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: Can it be without await ?   For example  apiGetInventory().then( response=>{ Your code } )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Top-level await must be used in combination with [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html) (which is experimental).

You should be able to just do it in `onBeforeMount`. Not as elegant; but a solid solution. Something like this:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { apiGetInventory, GetInventoryResponse } from '@/module/inventory/common/api/getInventory';
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue';

const inventory = ref<GetInventoryResponse>()

onBeforeMount( async () => {
    inventory.value = await apiGetInventory()
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `onBeforeMount` is good, but there are a couple of other options.

@skirtle suggested in Vue Discord chat to do the initialization inside an `async` lambda or function (possibly as an IIFE):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
let inventory: GetInventoryResponse
const loadData = async () => inventory = apiGetInventory()
loadData()
</script>
```

@wenfang-du suggested in [How can I use async/await in the Vue 3.0 setup() function using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117116/how-can-i-use-async-await-in-the-vue-3-0-setup-function-using-typescript/) to use promise chaining:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
let inventory: GetInventoryResponse 
apiGetInventory().then(d: GetInventoryResponse => inventory = d)
</script>
```

The benefit of doing so is that the code is run before the `beforeMount` lifecycle hook.

You additionally need to take care of error handling as appropriate in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

if you need for specific template(routes).
You can use router beforeResolve:

```js
import { apiGetInventory, GetInventoryResponse } from '@/module/inventory/common/api/getInventory'

let inventory = false
router.beforeResolve(async to => {
    // Skip if loaded or for specific vue file
    if (inventory || to.meta?.layout === 404 || to.meta?.layout === 'blank') {
        return
    }
    inventory = await apiGetInventory()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Vue3 documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await) says

> Top-level await can be used inside script setup. The resulting code will be compiled as async setup()
>
> In addition, the awaited expression will be automatically compiled in a format that preserves the current component instance context after the await.

For example:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { apiGetInventory, GetInventoryResponse } from '@/module/inventory/common/api/getInventory'
const inventory = ref(await apiGetInventory())
</script>
```

This only works if you use the Suspense compenent in the parent component, for instance:

```
<Suspense>
    <RouterView />
    <template #fallback>
      Loading...
    </template>
</Suspense>
```