# Vue export import async await stops

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, async-await, export

I use Vue and have a method in `load.js`.

```js
async function loadTask(x) {
  return await x; // Some async code
}

export { loadTask };
```

In a Vue component I call it but the `await` prevent the `<template>` to load. Without the `await`, the code below runs. What do I miss?

```html
<script setup>
import { loadTask } from './methods/load.js';
const test = loadTask(3);
console.log(await test);
</script>
<template>
  <div>Does not run</div>
</template>
```

Comment: `await` is not valid at the top level unless your environment supports it. I don't think a `<script>` tag counts for top-level await, though. Are you not getting an error saying something along those lines?

Comment: @VLAZ - It would if it were `<script type="module">` but the above isn't (unless something does something to it before the browser sees it, the `setup` thing on it makes  me wonder since I don't do Vue.js).

Comment: @VLAZ No, I'm not getting any errors. One strange thing, if I write console.log('whatever') before `</script>` it runs, but i stops the output in the `<template></template>`.

Comment: As @VLAZ said, most likely you're getting an error trying to use `await` at the top level outside a module. Perhaps the error is being obscured by a bundler or your environment?

Comment: @VLAZ `setup` is a new feature in Vue 3.2. https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Comment: You can use top level await in Vue, but it must be used together with Suspense:

1. https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183835/vue-script-setup-top-level-await-causing-template-not-to-render

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> async setup() must be used in combination with Suspense, which is
> currently still an experimental feature. We plan to finalize and
> document it in a future release - but if you are curious now, you can
> refer to its tests (opens new window)to see how it works.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/suspense.html#suspense

[Vue <script setup> Top level await causing template not to render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183835/vue-script-setup-top-level-await-causing-template-not-to-render)

So if you have async setup you have to import this component in parent like that:

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
      import("./components/HelloWorld.vue")
    ),
  },
};
</script>
```

And use it in template wrapped in suspense:

```
<template>
  <suspense>
    <template #default>
      <HelloWorld />
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </template>
  </suspense>
</template>
```

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-sinoussi-9r5or?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Vue <script setup> Top level await causing template not to render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183835/vue-script-setup-top-level-await-causing-template-not-to-render),
in case you don't need the full power of async components and `Suspense`, you can use either `onBeforeMount`:

```js
const test = ref('');
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  test.value = await loadTask(3);
  console.log(test.value);
})
```

or do the initialization inside an `async` function that you invoke without `await`ing for the promise to complete:

```js
const test = ref('');
const init = async () => {
  test.value = await loadTask(3);
  console.log(test.value);
}
init();
```

or use promise chainig:

```js
const test = ref('');
loadTask(3).then(task => {
  test.value = task;
  console.log(test.value);
});
```

You additionally need to take care of error handling as appropriate for each case.