# vue3 using await at top level to get ref() data, but can't render html data in <template>

Tags: vuejs3

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
      <div v-else>{{ data.value }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  const data = ref(null);
  const loading = ref(true);
  async function fetchData() {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        console.log("333");
        data.value = '<p>HTML</p>';

    loading.value = false;
  }
await fetchData();
</script>
```

Removing wait works, but I need to use wait to get the data asynchronously, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the tool versions you're using and targeting, but this thread may help you:

[How can I use async/await in the Vue 3.0 setup() function using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117116/how-can-i-use-async-await-in-the-vue-3-0-setup-function-using-typescript)

A simple `fetchData().then(() => {})` may be all you need.

But if that doesn't work, you will likely need to work with "Suspense". Check this page for more info straight from the Vue 3 docs:

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script

Comment: Solved the problem with <Suspense>, great!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to await fetchData() when calling it. The mistake was using data.value in template, when you should be using data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <div v-else>{{ data }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  const data = ref(null);
  const loading = ref(true);
  async function fetchData() {
     await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
     console.log("333");
     data.value = '<p>HTML</p>';

     loading.value = false;
 }
fetchData();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best approach is something like that:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const data = ref(null);
const loading = ref(true);
const fetchData = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  console.log('333');
  data.value = '<p>HTML</p>';

  loading.value = false;
};
fetchData();
</script>

<template>
   <div>
      <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
      <div v-else>{{ data }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

On the template you need to use **{{data}}** instead of *data.value*