# Unable to mark Vue setup function as async

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-suspense

I have a Vue3 app using the composition api and want to fetch data asynchronously inside the `setup` function.

Approaches that worked for me:

---

**Working with Promises**

```js
    <template>
      <div>{{ result }}</div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
    
    export default defineComponent({
      setup() {
        const result = ref();
    
        fetch("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
          .then((response: Response) => response.json())
          .then((jsonResponse: any) => {
            result.value = jsonResponse;
          });
    
        return { result };
      },
    });
    </script>
```

---

**Working with the `onMounted` hook**

```js
    <template>
      <div>
        {{ result }}
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
    
    export default defineComponent({
      setup() {
        const result = ref();
    
        onMounted(async () => {
          const response = await fetch("https://api.publicapis.org/entries");
          result.value = await response.json();
        });
    
        return { result };
      },
    });
    </script>
```

---

But I wasn't able to use async/await directly like so

```js
    <template>
      <Suspense>
        <template #default>
          {{ result }}
        </template>
        <template #fallback> Loading... </template>
      </Suspense>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
    
    export default defineComponent({
      async setup() {
        const result = ref();
    
        const response = await fetch("https://api.publicapis.org/entries");
        result.value = await response.json();
    
        return { result };
      },
    });
    </script>
```

Based on this question

[@vue-composition / How can I use asynchronous methods in setup()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230249/vue-composition-how-can-i-use-asynchronous-methods-in-setup)

and this linked article

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/suspense-new-feature-in-vue-3/

it should work.

The posted component is just the default **Home.vue** component rendered by the Vue router. So inside **App.vue** I'm using the tag `<router-view />` and load the app with the home route.

How can I mark `setup` as `async`?

Comment: You didn't show how the component is used. async setup should be used exclusively with suspense.

Comment: Give me a second, I will update my question

Comment: @EstusFlask it's just the Home.vue view component from the basic app skeleton generated by the CLI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First please **be careful** as `Suspense` is still experimental feature and can change any time...

In order to `async setup` to work, the component **itself** must be inside `<suspense>` ....your component is not inside `<suspense>` - it **contains** `<suspense>` component (which of course can not work until the component is created and that can happen only after your `async setup` resolves). You must place `<suspense>` as a child of `<router-view>` - [see the docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components)

Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-suspense-with-router-view-q4nsd) (if you see `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` first, just reload the right pane using the reload icon - seems like some glitch in the Matrix)

```js
// App.vue
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <suspense timeout="0">
    <template #default>
      <component :is="Component"></component>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </template>
  </suspense>
</router-view>
```

```js
// Home.vue
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <pre>{{ result }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    const result = ref();

    const response = await fetch("https://api.publicapis.org/entries");
    result.value = await response.json();

    return { result };
  },
});
</script>
```

Notice `timeout="0"` on `suspense` - [it seems](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/2099) there is a `timeout` for switching to a "loading" state (probably to avoid too much screen flickering when async components resolve quickly enough)

> A `timeout` prop can be specified - if a pending tree remains pending past the timeout threshold, the active tree will be unmounted and be replaced by the fallback tree.

I'm unable to find what is the default value for `timeout` right now. Feel free to tune it for your own needs...

Comment: Good one on timeout, didn't see it. I'd expect there's no timeout by default